# Learning PHP, array not working how it should

Tags: php

just learning some PHP.

The array below does not echo `"You own a $cars[0], its color is $color"`

However if I change, `$color` in `(in_array($color, $cars))` to `(in_array(toyota, $cars)),` it does echo `"You own a toyota, its color is blue"`

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$cars = array('toyota', 'nissan', 'honda'); 
$color = "blue";
if (in_array($color, $cars)) {
echo "<H1>You own a $cars[0], its color is $color</H1>";
}
else
{
echo "<H1>I don't know what kind of car you have, so I don't I
don't know the color either.</H1>";
}
?>
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Your colour "blue" is not the in array of cars. It would return true if you tested for something like "toyota".

Comment: This is because value "blue" doesn't exist in array $cars.

Comment: It would be cool if PHP would automatically recognize the colors of cars.

Answer (score 2):

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) Checks if a value exists in an `array` and `blue` is not in that array

in this case it will give you true result

```
if (in_array('toyota', $cars))
```

Comment: How should I code it to make it echo "You own a Toyota, its color is blue" instead of "I don't know what kind of car you have, so I don't I don't know the color either." which is the only thing I can get it to print now. Thanks.

Comment: $cars = array('toyota', 'nissan', 'honda'); 
$color = array('blue', 'black', 'red'); 
$car_color = "blue";
if (in_array($car_color, $color)) {
echo "<H1>You own a $cars[0], its color is $car_color</H1>";
}

Answer (score 2):

The value `blue` is certainly not in the array.

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) checks if the value exists in the given array and `blue` is not in that array.

Since you have `array('toyota', 'nissan', 'honda')`, the values that are there are `'toyota', 'nissan', 'honda'`.